# Efficient way to select elements touching top edge of viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

What would be computationally-efficient ways to select elements touching the top edge of browser window viewport as the page is scrolled?

See attached image. Green elements are selected because they are touching the top edge.

[image: scrolling]

**UPDATE**

An example of how I'll use this is to fade elements that are going off-screen. There may be hundreds of them on the page. Imagine a page like Pinterest. Computing offset and scrollTop for hundreds of them at the rate of scroll event, even if throttled still feels really inefficient.

Comment: there are several approaches you could take, to know which one is most optimal: will your script know the identities of all the elements you wish to detect (ie. is it a fixed # of elements)?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but why not just have a css element that is a gradient that goes from your background color to 0% opacity fixed to the top of the screen with a z-index of 99999 or something? Would not have to load any extra js or anything. Just a thought.

Comment: Because it blocks clicks in the fading region, for example - I have tried such a thing with inner box shadows once. Also, not all browsers do (and did in 2011) support gradient backgrounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I came up with. I think that it could be improved upon by caching the scrollTop values, but this is pretty good. I have included the framework for caching the boxtops, but not the implementation code. I have also only implemented scrolling down to hide divs. I have left reshowing them on upscroll as an exercise for you.

When the window is scrolled we get the last hidden div. We know that everything before this div is already hidden. Then use a 'while next element is off the screen' hide it. As soon as a div isn't off the screen we abort. Thus saving time from iterating through the entire list.

http://jsfiddle.net/kkv3h/2/

```
//track whether user has scrolled up or down
var prevScrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();

$(document).scroll(function() {
    var currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (currentScrollTop > prevScrollTop) {
        //down
        var lasthiddenbox = $('.fadeboxhidden:last');
        var nextbox = (lasthiddenbox.length > 0) ? lasthiddenbox.next('.fadebox') : $('.fadebox:first');
        while (nextbox.length) {
            console.log('box: ' + nextbox.offset().top + ' scroll: ' + currentScrollTop);
            if (nextbox.offset().top < currentScrollTop) {
                nextbox.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 3000).addClass('fadeboxhidden');
            }
            else { return; } 
            nextbox = nextbox.next('.fadebox:first');
        }        
    } else {
        //up          
    }
    prevScrollTop = currentScrollTop ;
});

//create an object to hold a list of box top locations
var boxtops = new Object;


//gather all boxes and store their top location
$('.fadebox').each( function(index) {    
    //you may want to dynamically generate div ids here based on index. I didn't do this
    //because i was already using the id for positioning.
    var divid = $(this).prop('id');
    boxtops[divid] = $(this).offset().top;
    //console.log(boxtops[divid]);    
});
```

Comment: how to reverse this?.. I mean when scroll up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the best way would be that you could mark elements you want to determine hit testing with by some class, say "hit-test-visible" or something. Then, for those elements, on the scroll event, you should be able to find their offset compared to the document - see [jQuery offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), and then based on the scroll value, if the offset is less than the scroll, and the offset + element height is greater than the scroll offset, then the element should be "touching" the top edge.